# What is the proper hebrew pronunciation of Rav Hirsch's first name?

Tags: names, pronunciation, samson-raphael-hirsch

Among the Modern Orthodox I hear Rav Hirsch's name only said in its English form ("Samson"). Amongst the Yeshivish I hear the form "Shamshon." My question is, was his Hebrew name Shamshon or Shimshon?

( *While choosing a tag for this, I see this site has all the variants as tags!* )

Comment: I think his name was "Shamshon," but can't prove it.

Comment: http://onthemainline.blogspot.com/2011/11/so-whats-up-with-shamshon.html

Comment: isn't this a dupe somewhere?

Comment: @Double AA I looked but did not find.

Comment: @Menachem that is a GREAT article, so thanks. It proves that the name Shamshon exists, I happen to know a couple of them, but it doesn't convince me what Rav Hirsch got called up for his aliya by.

Comment: Also it's *Shamshon* Charitonov

Comment: @Shmuel Brin I'll admit my ignorance, I had never heard of him so I googled. First article I read had Shimshon!

Comment: First 15 seconds: http://www20.chassidus.com/audio/nigun/11-37-Volach-V-Koreiv-Pezureinu-from-Reb-Sholom-Charitonow-of-Nikolayev-Heichal-Neginah.mp3

Comment: @Shmuel Brin thanks. Was worth a listen conversation notwithstanding.

Comment: I think this is the same kind of question as "How does 'Yosef Dov' become 'Yoshe Ber'"

Comment: Is this on topic? This seems to be about Jews not Judaism.

Comment: @DoubleAA http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/4101