# What "really" occurred with Moshe having to ask G-d a "halachic" question?

Tags: midrash, moshe-rabbeinu, parashat-shelach, parshat-korach

I begin with Rashi's explanation on [Vayikra 25:1](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9754&st=&pgnum=332&hilite=) that says that all the mitzvoth including their details were mentioned to Moshe at Mt. Sinai.

Assuming this explanation, why did Moshe not know the details of inheritance laws when Tzelfachad's daughters asked him, and he had to wait for G-d's explanation? (Bemidbar 27:5) Did G-d not explain this detail to Moshe at Mt. Sinai, for some reason? Did Moshe forget something? Was Moshe confused about something that he learned and needed it re-explained?

I would apply this question to these other scenarios where Moshe asked G-d for "details", specifically:

- [Bemidbar 15:34](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14084&st=&pgnum=194) - form of punishment for the Shabbat twig gatherer
- [Bemidbar 9:8](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14084&st=&pgnum=106&hilite=) - unclean people who could not offer Pesach sacrifice
- [Bemidbar 36:5](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14084&st=&pgnum=464) - Tzlefachad's daughters ask regarding land inheritance if they marry someone from another tribe (the question to G-d is implied by the phrasing in the verse.)

Comment: there is precedent for "forgot" -- https://yeshivakessertorah.org/written/3-Shmini.html

Comment: duplicate? https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2181/603

Comment: @Menachem Good find! I'm closing this as a self-marked dupe.